# Subtraction calculation for the same variables differs in different situations

Tags: php, math, subtraction

Problem is bit critical. Output I need is `2.9558577807620168e-12`.

1#working.php

```
 <?php 
     $a = 465.90928248188;
     $b = 15.651243716447;
     $c = 450.25803876543; 

     echo $a - $b -$c // output 2.9558577807620168e-12 as expected
 ?>
```

2#notworking.php

```
<?php 

     lot of arithmetic calculation almost 200-250 LoC
     $array1_28x1[3]; // 465.90928248188
     $array2_28x1[3]; // 15.651243716447
     $array3_28x1[3]; // 450.25803876543

     echo $array1_28x1[3] - $array2_28x1[3] - $array3_28x1[3];
     // output -4.5474735088646E-13

 ?>
```

I Don't understand what is the issue. Can it be memory leak? I have done step by step debugging also but could not find any solution. And this is very important calculation so can not even ignore.

Note: There is no changes in the variable's value under those 250 LoC. I have dumped variables before the subtraction.

Comment: Did you write `array2_...` *twice* on purpose in the echo line? Info above says `array3_...`.

Comment: can you `var_dump($array1_28x1[3])` and other 2 vars

Comment: Calculations are type dependent. Each type has a different precision. You are pushing this to a limit with floats that range between 1E2 and 1E-13. That's 16 steps of 10. See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php "Although it depends on the system, PHP typically uses the IEEE 754 double precision format, which will give a maximum relative error due to rounding in the order of 1.11e-16."

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I'd hardly call reaching one-thousandth of a **maximum** relative error "pushing it to a limit".

Comment: @ccKep: You're mistaken, the calculation involves also numbers in the hunderds... crossing the zero point.

Comment: Echoing @MittulAtTechnoBrave : You need to display the values with 17 significant decimal digits to get reproducible numerical results. You only give 14 digits, 64bit `double` provides about 15.5 significant digits, i.e., the binary format is only uniquely determined from 16, better 17 digits.

Comment: @LutzL Ah .. makes sense.

Comment: @LutzL Can you give some code example. I don't understand it exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem arises since you display your intermediate variables with only 14 significant digits. This hides 2 additional digits that are present in the original computation but missing in the reconstruction.

The general solution is to recognize that within the bounds of floating point arithmetic, you have effectively computed zero.

To get a reconstructable result you could convert the intermediate results to strings which are displayed and then those back to numbers. This will trivially give you results that can be reproduced from the displayed intermediate results.

As to having a result that is essentially floating point noise and thus represents zero, your scale/magnitude of inputs is 1000, which gives a absolute error scale resp. scale of floating point noise of `1e4*1e-16=1e-12`. Both indicated results fall within this scale, i.e., both have to be considered to be zero.

Comment: We can guess all we want, using the same values [gives the correct/expected output](https://3v4l.org/MRQe7) in all PHP versions - so I don't think OP is using the variables he thinks he's using or those 200-250 LOC change those variables to something the OP's not expecting.

Comment: No, the problem in the question is that using rounded values as inputs will give you a different result than using the original values. The computation with the 250 lines before uses variables that have additional unknown 2.5 digits, and those make all the difference.

Comment: That should fall under "or those 200-250 LOC change those variables to something the OP's not expecting." - **if** those numbers he posted however are the numbers exactly before the echo then that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Yeah, but again, OP's problem is exactly that displaying doubles with 14 digits will not be "the numbers exactly".

Comment: @LutzL If I understood your answer correctly, you mean I should use 16 decimals instead of 14 right?

Comment: @LutzL Initially it was  complex for me to understand what you described but I tried converting array value to string and than subtraction. I can't belive it worked. Hats off :)

Answer (score 5):

You did use 2 times the array2, so i think it is a typo.
when i execute this code it works:

```
<?php 

     $array1_28x1[3] = 465.90928248188;
     $array2_28x1[3] = 15.651243716447;
     $array3_28x1[3] = 450.25803876543;

     echo $array1_28x1[3] - $array2_28x1[3] - $array3_28x1[3];
     // output 2.955857780762E-12
```

Comment: But you note that if he had actually executed the displayed code, the result would not have been close to zero as indicated in the comment?

Comment: @Ricardo Yes. It works in simple scenario but when I use the same calculation with the same type and value I get different result while long calculation as I mentioned

Comment: Could you do a var_dump of the arrays?

Comment: yes I have done it shows the same values with float data type.